# Access violation - cannot write to location

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a code for a linked list but when I try to add a node the code gets stuck at the line immediately after the while loop in the add() function, reporting an access violation error. What's wrong?

```
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class linkedlist
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node *lp;
    }*p;
public:
    linkedlist();
    void add(T t);
};

template<class T>
void linkedlist<T>::add(T t)
{
    node *r,*q;
    r = q = p;

    while(p!= NULL)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->lp;
    }

    q->lp = new node;
    q->lp->data = t;
    p = r;
}

template<class T>
linkedlist<T>::linkedlist()
{
    p = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    linkedlist<int> l1;
    l1.add(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `p` to `NULL` in the constructor, then try to dereference it in `add` (via `q`):

```
r = q = p;
// the while loop will not be executed as p == NULL
q->lp = new node;
```

You must initialize `p` first - either during construction (in which case your "empty" list won't be physically empty, so you must deal with this specifically, e.g. when iterating / removing elements), or you should check in `add` for the case when `p == null` and handle it differently.

Side note: `p` is supposed to point to your head element, so it is risky to use it also to iterate through the list in `add`, then restore its original value (stored in `r`). Why not simply leave it always intact, and use `r` for iterating? One less chance for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the node in the constructor:

```
p = new Node;
```

Because here:

```
while(p!= NULL)
{
    q = p;
    p = p->lp;
}

q->lp = new node;
```

`p` is initially `NULL`, so `q` will also be `NULL`, ergo `q->lp` leads to **undefined behavior** and a crash.

Either initialize `p` or re-think your logic.

Comment: *You should initialize the node in the constructor*, NO, One should do that in the **Member Initialization List**.

Comment: @Als isn't that part of the constructor? :P

Comment: Can the code statement you mentioned be added in the Member Initialization List? It cannot, It could be only in the constructor body.So your answer and your comment are tangential.

Comment: @Als Actually, can it? I tried and it works. Could it be legal? http://ideone.com/AOBW2